# How to read data from one particular partition of kafka into druid using kafka supervisor

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

We are trying to create a Kafka supervisor task in druid.

Our Kafka topic has multiple partitions in it and we would like to listen to specific partition using a kafka supervisor task.

How can we specify the partition id to read from in ingestion spec ?
Is it possible to read from specific partition instead of reading from whole kafka topic..?

Comment: What is the use-case for this? Can't you filter by partition in Druid afterwards?

Comment: After reading through the documentation of Druid, I did not see this kind of option

Comment: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/filters.html , but you might use filters in ingestion phase , Filter
The filter conditionally filters input rows during ingestion. Only rows that pass the filter will be ingested. Any of Druid's standard query filters can be used. Note that within a transformSpec, the transforms are applied before the filter, so the filter can refer to a transform.

Comment: Ran Lupovich  - Is it possible to add a filter in ingestion spec  to pull data from only specific partitions of kafka topic ??

Comment: @OneCricketeer - usecase is basically we wanted to get each kafka partitions data into individual data source.. so we need to create one data source per partition in kafka

Comment: That implies that each partition has a different schema? Or if the values are all the same schema and your key denotes the source, then you could filter by the key in Druid because all the same keys map to the same partition

Comment: Is there a way to read from one partition of kafka topic without using filters ? As we are seeing lot of "thrownAway" messages under each supervisor and its slowing down the processing. If we can directly connect to one particular partition of kafka and pull data - we can get rid of that additional processing ?